# Navigation bar buttons stack on top of each other when browser window is re-sized

Tags: html, css

This navigation bar rearranges itself when the browser window is re-sized, all of the buttons go from being in a straight horizontal line to stacking on top of each other, one by one, as the window is made smaller and smaller. How can they be set to stay in place and stick nicely to the bottom of the header logo, no matter what size the window is?

Screenshot of problem:
http://s29.postimg.org/3tnroxls7/Screenshot1.png

Screenshot of goal:
http://s24.postimg.org/vzuruvqb9/Screenshot2.png

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

header img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid #0009bc;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

a:link, a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 139px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #20dbd4;
  background-color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  background-color: #20dbd4;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow, noarchive"/>
<title>Grid Design</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="/images/grid-design.jpg" alt="Grid Design" style="width: 987px; height: 243px;"/>
  </header>
  <nav>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">news</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#products">products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#photos">photos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get right, you just want the menu to stay the same size and to stay in line, right? So you could just add a width to your `<ul>`

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 978px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid #0009bc;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mghL5vx8/) here.

Answer (score 0):

When you are talking about resizing and respsonsivness you should already be thinking about widths in percentages. For example you have 6 li-s which u are trying to fit in a 100% width...Which means each li should have 16.66% width. In theory this should all work and wrap up nicely, but because of whitespace your problem will persist. To fix that you need to fight the whitespace. refference here: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

```
nav{

 width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```